# Prevent an instance of NSView from receiving mouse events

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsview, nsviewanimation

I have an NSView in a window with core animation layer turned on.
I use this view to display images with animation from time to time. I need the entire view to be the back layer not only the images. Behind this view which I call AnimationBaseView are other views which the user interacts to.

Everything is ok except the AnimationBaseView prevents the other views from getting rightMouseDown events.

I've tried the following:

- returning NO to acceptsFirstResponder to AnimationBaseView
- Hiding and unhiding the AnimationBaseView as needed, but produces a nasty flicker.

Thank you for your help,
Jose.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Override `- (NSView *)hitTest:(NSPoint)aPoint` to return either `nil` or the view that should handle the mouse events